# How fix put method erorr

Tags: put

i want to update users, but always get 404 (Cannot PUT /api/users). Calling api/users to router.put('/:id' , What am i missing? How do you solve users update thing?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Help us help you, and put the actual code into your question instead of using screenshots. See the question editor's help for how to mark it as code..

Comment: @Darryl Noakes ` router.post("/:id", async(req, res) => {
    if (req.body.userId === req.params.id) {
        if (req.body.password) {
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
            req.body.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt)
        }`

Comment: @Darryl Noakes
try {
            const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
                $set: req.body, 
            })
            res.status(200).json(updatedUser)
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json(error)
        }
    } else {
        res.status(401).json("You Only Update Other Account")
    }

Answer (score 0):

The code 404 means that the API endpoint is not found.
Your users API is listening for `/users/:id`, and then that is attached under `api/users`.
This means that the actual path that Express is listening on is `/api/users/users/:id`.

Change the `/users/:id` to `/:id` and it should work.

Comment: still not running